# How to process Previous value of object in list item in drool rule engine?

Tags: drools, rule, business-rules

> I want Drool to fire rule in all elements of list
>
> Here is my Order class

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Order {

    public static final int ORDER_AMOUNT_LIMIT = 10;
    public static final int DEFAULT_VALUE=0;

    public int id  ;
    public String name;
    public OrderItem item;
    public String code;
    public List<String> message=new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addmessage(String m) {
        message.add(m);
    }




    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public List<OrderItem> orderItems = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

    public OrderItem getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(OrderItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    Order(int id,String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name =  name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addOrderItem(OrderItem item) {
        orderItems.add(item);
}

}
```

> OrderItem.java

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderItem {

    public static final int TEMP_PRICE = 0; 

    public Order order;
    public int price;
    public String code;
    public List<String> message=new ArrayList();

    public  void addMessage(String msg){
        message.add(msg);
    }


    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    OrderItem(Order order,int price){
        this.order = order;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }



}
```

> order.drl

```
 package com.sample
import com.sample.Order;

rule "order"
when
    $order : Order()
     $total : Double() from accumulate( OrderItem( order == $order, $price : price,code == $order.code,),
                              sum( $price ) )


   eval($total>Order.ORDER_AMOUNT_LIMIT)
then
   System.out.println($total);
   $order.orderItems.get(0).price=0;

   System.out.println("price is "+ $order.orderItems.get(0).getPrice());
end
```

> DroolTest.java

```
public class DroolsTest {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // load up the knowledge base
            KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
            KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");


            Order order =  new Order(1,"bob");
            order.setCode("test1");

            OrderItem item1 =  new OrderItem(order, 11);
            item1.setCode("test1");
            OrderItem item2 =  new OrderItem(order, 7);
            item2.setCode("test1");

            order.addOrderItem(item1);
            order.addOrderItem( item2 );


            kSession.insert(order);
            kSession.insert(item1);

            kSession.fireAllRules();


            kSession.insert(item2);
            kSession.fireAllRules();            

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

> Output

```
11.0
price is 0
```

> As you can see the then condition is executed only by once  because
>   when drools check 11 > 10 which is working fine  and set the value to
>   0 but when drools process second list item  now sum will return 0+7 >
>   10 which is false  but i want to fire then condition on second list
>   item because 11+7 = 19 is greater than 10  Is there any way to fire
>   then condition on both list item ? Is there any way we get the
>   original value of the object not from working memory?

Answer (score 0):

You add a pattern OrderItem so the rule will fire for each item of an order exceeding the limit.

```
rule "order"
when
  $order: Order( $code: code )
  accumulate( OrderItem( order == $order, $price: price,
                         code == $code );
              $total: sum( $price );
              $total > Order.ORDER_AMOUNT_LIMIT )
  $item: OrderItem( order == $order, $price: price, code == $code )
then
   System.out.println( $item ); // an order item of a "big" order

end
```